# capture word based on a symbol

Tags: python, regex

I have a a bunch of strings like this: "Today I sold MSFT 100@50 and then went to bed!"

So I want to parse out 3 strings and make them into variables. I want to parse out sold, 100, 50.

So when I use (bought|sold).*(\d+)@(\d+) the first (\d+) returns 0, when I want to return 100.

Comment: What's the pattern? Please explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand based on your edit:

```
(bought|sold).*?(\d+)@(\d+)
```

The trick here is that, in your example, ".*" matches as many characters as possible, leaving only one digit matched by the subsequent "\d+". Adding the '?' makes it ungreedy, so it'll match as few characters as possible.

Comment: `\w+@\d+` might provide the OP with a tighter match, but of course we're only guessing here

Comment: @jaytea Also changing from `\w+@\w+` to `\w*@\w*` won't fail in case the OP has `MSFT@` or `@50` only

Comment: What if the string is "Today I sold MSFT 100@50 and then went to bed!"? I'm only picking up "0@50" using the regex.

Comment: @A1122 try with `re.find_all(r'\w*@\w*',x)[0]` (where x is the sentence).

Comment: @A1122 I think what you mean to say is you're only picking up "100@50" whereas what you want is "MSFT 100@50". Without knowing too much about the nature of the data you're dealing with, we can only speculate as to what a correct expression for your purposes would be (as you can see by the other comments on my post). I guess these are stock market transactions, but I'm personally unfamiliar as to their general format.

Comment: Sorry -- I actually want to pick up "100@50" and then split 100 and 50 into 2 variables based on @.

Answer (score 0):

If the text would be consistent like "MSFT@50", then you could use the following:

```
import re
re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+@[0-9]+', <your srting here>)
```

Hope it helps